# How to flash pre-compiled bin files into NodeMCU using Ardunio IDE

Tags: arduino-ide, nodemcu

How to flash pre-compiled binary into NodeMCU using Ardunio IDE. Since every time it require to compile and flash it. Is there way to flash binary alone to nodeMCU via Arduino IDE ?

One can export binary file from IDE -> Sketch -> Export Compiled Binary. Binary will be copied into working directory. U can check the path Sketchbook location in File -> Preferences. But how to flash binary alone to nodeMCU.

I have fashed using esptool.py from linux. But is there a way to flash from IDE for handy ?

Comment: I'm viewing from my phone right now, so can't really add a decent answer. Take a look at this [guide](https://www.agcross.com/2015/09/the-esp8266-wifi-chip-part-3-flashing-custom-firmware/#FlashingArduinoIDE) and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can't flash precompiled binary with Arduino IDE, you have to use esptool.py from the command line.